# populate a formview using linq - vs2010 c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formview

Using Linq I have built a query which I return to a gridview.
This works fine but I want to populate a formview with the same data,
can anyone point me to a decent how-to article please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign your query result to a `DataSource` property, then try to execute `DataBind()` method.. it should work.. if not, please provide us some code...

Regards..

Comment: Id got that far before, its the binding of the fields within the formview to the query field Im not sure of - thanks